# Clear data in angular form

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have the following angular form:

```
<form name="client_form" id="client_form" role="form">
  <div class="bb-entry">
    <label for="firstname">First Name:*</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="client.first_name" required class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="bb-entry">
    <label for="lasttname">Last Name:*</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="client.last_name" required class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="bb-entry">
    <label for="email">E-mail:*</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="client.email" required class="form-control"/>
  </div>
</form>
<button type="button" ng-click="resetForm(client_form)">Clear</button>
```

I would like to add behaviour so that when users select 'Clear', all form data is cleared. I've written this method at present:

```
resetForm: (form) ->
  form.submitted = false
  form.$setPristine()
  angular.copy({}, client)
```

However, this clears the entire client object, when really, I only want to clear the attributes referenced in my form.

I realise I can iterate around each attribute of the form object, which gives me access to the ngModelController instances as such:

```
resetForm: (form,) ->
    form.submitted = false
    form.$setPristine()
    angular.forEach form, (value, key) ->
      if value.hasOwnProperty("$modelValue")
        # set model value here?
```

But can I actually assign the model value here or would a different approach be better?

Comment: Why not just `<input type='reset' value='Clear' />` That will clear the entire form, and then if you need to call something when that is clicked just use `onclick`

Comment: Hey @pattyd, that visibly clears the form fields, but doesn't appear to clear the data in the underlying model?

Comment: Thats why you need to set `onclick`. Set the `onclick` function to clear that data

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to copy the client first, then clear the new client object.

Here is a fiddle link that does something very similar: http://jsfiddle.net/V44fQ/

```
$scope.editClient = function(client) {
    $scope.edit_client = angular.copy(client);
}

$scope.cancelEdit = function() {
    $scope.edit_client = {};
};

<form name="client_form" id="client_form" role="form">
  <div class="bb-entry">
    <label for="firstname">First Name:*</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="edit_client.first_name" required class="form-control">
  </div>
  ...
  <button type="button" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by writing two directives, one that is attached to the form and the other to each individual input that I want to be 'resettable'.  The directive attached to the form then adds a resetForm() method to the parent controller:

```
# Adds field clearing behaviour to forms.  
app.directive 'bbFormResettable', ($parse) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  controller: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
    $scope.inputs = []

    $scope.resetForm = () ->
      for input in $scope.inputs
        input.getter.assign($scope, null)
        input.controller.$setPristine()

    registerInput: (input, ctrl) ->
      getter = $parse input
      $scope.inputs.push({getter: getter, controller: ctrl})


# Registers inputs with the bbFormResettable controller allowing them to be cleared
app.directive 'bbResettable', () ->
  restrict: 'A',
  require: ['ngModel', '^bbFormResettable'],
  link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) ->
    ngModelCtrl        = ctrls[0]
    formResettableCtrl = ctrls[1]
    formResettableCtrl.registerInput(attrs.ngModel, ngModelCtrl)
```

Probably overkill, but this solution ensures only the attributes specified are cleared, not the entire client object.

Answer (score -1):

No need to complicate things. Just clean the scope variables in your controller.

Plain JS:

```
$scope.resetForm = function() {
    $scope.client.first_name = '';
    $scope.client.last_name = '';
    $scope.client.email = '';
}
```

If you wish, you can parse the $scope.client object and set properties to false (if the form is dynamic, for example).

---

Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/DLL3W/

Comment: That's a rather ugly solution. Maintaining (or writing, for that matter) this when you have a large form is a mess.

Comment: @dirkk That's why I said there are many ways to handle this... I just gave the OP the launchpad so he can get a working code and move on. Personally, I'd just set the `$scope.client` to an empty object and never worry about that form again.

Comment: In this case, I don't want to set '$scope.client' to an empty object as there's attributes I want to keep.  Ideally, I only want to clear the attributes used in the form.

Comment: @LukeFerguson Yeah, I have no idea what the whole app looks like, so didn't want to go too deep into it. But anyway, you have plenty of choices from this point - you can clear the necessary properties manually; store them in an array and check the client object against them; create a new scope variable just for the form and update the client from it; etc...